# Aggregate in where clause of LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to write a LINQ statement which selects only the rows in a table with the most recent rundate.  For example, if I had a table with columns RunDate(datetime) and Value(decimal) one way of accomplishing this through sql might look like:

```
SELECT Value
FROM Table
WHERE RunDate = (SELECT MAX(RunDate) FROM Table)
```

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the rows:

```
var rows = Table.Where(row => row.RunDate == Table.Max(r => r.RunDate));
```

If you just want the values:

```
var values = Table.Where(row => row.RunDate == Table.Max(r => r.RunDate))
                  .Select(row => row.Value);
```

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly...i'm brand new to LINQ if you couldn't tell

Comment: We were all there at some point. We will all never go back. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Table.OrderByDescending(row=>row.RunDate).Take(1);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the same thing... that will only give back one record, even if there are several rows with the same run date.